# How to use PersistentVolume for PostgreSQL data in Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

We are developing Web-server by Flask & DB-server by PostgreSQL in Kubernetes, and considering to use PersistentVolume in order to make data persistent.

However, for the directory specified as Volume, the ownership is forced to become ‘root’ user.

In PostgreSQL, if the user and owner do not match, the server can not be set up.
And, we can not set up a server under the user=‘root’.
So, we can not make PostgreSQL server data persistent.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ARG project_dir=/app/

WORKDIR $project_dir

RUN apt update
RUN apt install --yes python3 python3-pip postgresql-9.5
RUN apt clean
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip

RUN pip install flask
RUN pip install flask_sqlalchemy
RUN pip install psycopg2

ADD app.py $project_dir
ADD templates/ $project_dir/templates/

USER postgres

RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start && \
  psql --command "CREATE USER docker WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'docker';" && \
  createdb -O docker docker

RUN echo "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5" >> /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf

EXPOSE 5000

CMD /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf & python /app/app.py
```

development.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dummyproject
  labels:
    app: dummyproject
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dummyproject
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dummyproject
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: dummyproject
        image: dummyproject:0.1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/
          name: mydata
      volumes:
        - name: mydata
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: nfs-claim1
```

Please let me know if you know the solution.

Comment: Hi. Good question. This used to be problem 3 years ago. I dont know how specifically this solution will be of use to you. But Kubernetes has introduced groupids you can use to given ownership. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/

Comment: `spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
        runAsUser: 0`

Comment: To Siddarth Sreeni:  Thank you for your comments. I'll try these methods.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to run PostgreSQL as root. Root in the container is not the same as root on a bare Linux machine. UID==0 doesn't imply superpowers anymore. Nowadays user access is controlled with the mechanism of capabilities, and your container won't have any dangerous capabilities by default (unless you explicitly ask Kubernetes for some).

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here:

1. Set UID to 0 in the container, as @Alexandr Lurye told above. That is more or less secure now.
2. You can use `InitContainer` to change the owner. That is my answer how to do it - https://serverfault.com/questions/906083/how-to-mount-volume-with-specific-uid-in-kubernetes-pod/907160#907160